# Complex sql query and JPQL

Tags: jpql

How to change this complex sql statement into JPQL?

```
select a.name, a.surname, b.street, c.location, c.location_desc
from table1 join table2 on b.id = a.some_fk
left join table3 d on d.id = a.id
left join table4 c on c.some2_id = d.some2_fk where a.id = 400;
```

If this is possible to present in the JPQL form?

Answer (score 0):

Impossible to give a definitive answer without knowing the entities and their mapping, but the query would look like this:

```
select a.name, a.surname, b.street, c.location, c.locationDesc
from Entity1 a 
join a.entity2 b
left join a.entity3 d 
left join d.entity4 c 
where a.id = 400;
```

provided the necessary associations between entities are there.

Answer (score 0):

JPQL is object oriented, it operates against JPA entity objects ,not database tables. Either you need to change the Question and add an UML diagramm or provide the Entity classes.