# Relationships between JPQL, Java (and the Oracle DB)

Tags: java, jpql

I am confused about the above relationship.

My Oracle DB Tables:

```
xd_Users: user_id (pk), client_id (fk), name, doj, email, dol
xd_Managers: manager_id (pk), user_id (fk)
```

Corresponding Java Entities User and Manager relate to the above two tables respectively. Manager and User are separate, not related by inheritance, and have fields that correspond to the DB tables.

In my application, a Manager has to be a User.

I am writing the a(n as yet unfinished) method (in a class called `PersistService`) to retrieve a list of users who are managers.

```
public static ArrayList<User> getManagersForClient(Client client) {
    Long clientId = client.getClientId();
    EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
    String sqlQuery = "SELECT u FROM XD_USERS u, XD_MANAGERS m WHERE u.CLIENT_ID = :clientId";
    TypedQuery<User> query = em.createQuery(sqlQuery, User.class);
    query = query.setParameter("clientId", clientId);
    ArrayList<User> clientUsers = (ArrayList<User>) query.getResultList();
    for (User user : clientUsers) {

    }
    return clientUsers;
}
```

The pseudo-sql query I constructed was (:client_id at the end is just the java variable, hence the pseudo-sql):

```
select * from users u join managers m on u.user_id = m.user_id where u.client_id = :client_id;
```

I am having trouble converting this to a valid JPQL query. I don't understand how to think about solving this. In particular, the relationship between the identification variable, the single-valued relationship field, the collection-valued relationship field and the persistent field is very confusing. And I am even more confused by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13572493/complex-sql-query-and-jpql) post. Please help!

Comment: Just as the answer to the linked question says: JPQL works on entities, not tables. And yet, you haven't posted the code of your entities, but the description of your tables, which is irrelevant. And you also name your variable `sqlQuery`, although you know it's not SQL, but JPQL.

Answer (score 0):

If you have coded the related entities correctly then your sql select query is something like this in jpql (according to the structure of related tables you gave):

```
select u.userId,u.name,u.doj,u.email, u.dol, m.managerId
from User u 
join u.manager m 
where u.clientId = :client_id;
```